# Insert <input id='name'> value inside <img src=.....>

Tags: javascript, php, html, string, image

How can I insert a value stored inside an input box into img scr= tag.
I found this code to create barcode

```
<div id="aggiungi" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="invio">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">     
                    <div style='text-align: center;'>
                    <!-- insert your custom barcode setting your data in the GET parameter "data" -->
                       <img alt='Barcode Generator TEC-IT'src='https://barcode.tec-it.com/barcode.ashx?data=Nome%5Ct+Cognome%5Cn&code=&multiplebarcodes=false&translate-esc=true&unit=Fit&dpi=96&imagetype=Gif&rotation=0&color=%23000000&bgcolor=%23ffffff&codepage=Default&qunit=Mm&quiet=0&hidehrt=False'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='padding-top:8px; text-align:center; font-size:15px; font-family: Source Sans Pro,   Arial, sans-serif;'>
                    <!-- back-linking to www.tec-it.com is required -->
                        <a href='https://www.tec-it.com' title='Barcode Software by TEC-IT' target='_blank'>
                        TEC-IT Barcode Generator<br/>
                            <!-- logos are optional -->
                            <img alt='TEC-IT Barcode Software' border='0' src='http://www.tec-it.com/pics/banner/web/TEC-IT_Logo_75x75.gif'>
                        </a>
                     </div>
                </div>
          </form>
 </div>
```

I would like to change Nome and Cognome inside the scr=.... using the value inserted into two input box like these:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="cognome" name="cognome">
```

Eventually I have these two variables stored also inside two javascrip variables (javascript function)

PS in edit:
**The code is inside a bootstrap modal**

[image]

As you can see from the image Nome & Cognome below the barcode must take the values inserted in the input boxes. Really I'm trying to show the barcode only when all input boxes are filled. I already have Nome & Cognome declared as javascript variable (var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value; and the same for cognome) inside another javascript function, called by a onkeyup event on these two input boxes. My problem is how to change them inside img scr=...I tried to insert as < script>.... or as <?php ... but without positive result

Comment: This can be done with javascript. Just like normal DOM manipulation. But do it carefully because it may open up possibility of XSS attack.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is a problem about modification of parts of the url string (in your case its `data` parameter) with variable arguments obtaining the expected url.
It is possible to solve the problem manipulating the url parametes with [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) like below :

```js
let url = new URL('https://barcode.tec-it.com/barcode.ashx?data=Nome%5Ct+Cognome');
let nome = "nameValue";
let cognome = "surnameValue";
const data = `${nome}\\t ${cognome}`;
url.searchParams.set("data", data);
//it prints https://barcode.tec-it.com/barcode.ashx?data=nameValue%5Ct+surnameValue
console.log(url);
```

Then you can store the new url as the src attribute of your img tag.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I don't understand how: let nome & let cognome can take the new values from the input boxes. Also, don't understand how the new url can be inserted in the img scr at the top of my code.

Comment: @MassimoD.N.  You are welcome, you have to use [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById?retiredLocale=it) with the input boxes and extract `value` property, same approach with the img and its `src` property that you can set to the new value. You should create a button in your page that when clicked triggers the event , see [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for an example.

Comment: @MassimoD.N. `document.getElementById("imageid").src= 'new link'` or similar works.